# How to escape XML characters in a groovy Jenkinsfile without calling static method

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile, I need to construct an XML string composed of parameter values.  Some of the values need to be "xml escaped" so they can be set as XML attributes.

One apparently simple way to do that is to call "XmlUtil.escapeXml(text)" (although I guess that doesn't do spaces).

However, this fails at a high-level because Jenkinsfile doesn't allow calling static methods.

What is the simplest strategy for doing this sort of thing in a Jenkinsfile?

**Update**:

After remembering some more Groovy principles, I realized MarkupBuilder would be the solution for this, but it doesn't even allow that: "Scripts not permitted to use new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder".

**Update**:

ok, I've been able to override the security restrictions, but now I'm seeing issues with using the MarkupBuilder DSL within the Pipeline DSL.

I defined the following method at the end of my Jenkinsfile (after the overall "node" block):

```
def constructMessageXML(String qid, String qpassword, String contactID, String text, boolean isMeeting) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    MarkupBuilder mb    = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    mb.message (type:"contact.send.message", id:qid, password:qpassword, contactId:contactID) {
        statement (isMeeting ? [from:qid, to:contactID, text:text, type:"meeting"] : [from:qid, to:contactID, text:text]) {}
    }
    return writer.toString()
}
```

I tested this in groovyConsole, and it works fine.

However, when I run my job that calls this method, I get the following:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'statement' found
>   among steps [VersionNumber, archive, awaitDeployment, ...

The listed steps there are from the Pipeline DSL, so it appears that the "methodMissing" lookup is going to the Pipeline DSL, not the MarkupBuilder class.

Note that I tried adding "@NonCPS" to the method definition.  That made no difference.

**Update**:

I've found a solution for this.  Changing "statement" to "delegate.statement" gets past this.